# How can I deploy multiple mobile apps from a single code base (one per customer)?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mobile, xamarin, app-store

We have a multi-tenant web app and we are expanding into the mobile space.  We've built a native mobile version of our app and we'd like to deploy it as an "app per customer/tenant" so that each of our customers has their own app in the app store.  Each deployment would have trivial customization but the code base would be the same.

How can this be achieved using Visual Studio?  Is there reference material on this approach?  Is there a common definition for this approach (e.g. multi-tentant-single-codebase-mobile). :)

We're using Xamarin for cross-platform support (just an fyi).

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished through putting all your shared code within a `Android Library Project` and then creating an `Android Application Project` for each application package that references the library project.

### Tutorial

Go to Xamarin Studio and create a new project. Under **Android** there is a project type called **Android Library Project**; this projects can contain all your shared shared code and resources that will be linked into the final application.

[image]

For this sample I am calling my shared project `SharedCode.Core`.

After you've created this project, create another project, this time using the **Android Application Project** type:

[image]

The Android application project (SharedCode.ClientOne) can reference this shared project using the normal referencing system in Xamarin. Double click on the references folder to open the dialog, you will see `SharedCode.Core` is available as a reference. Tick the check-box to include it into `SharedCode.ClientOne`.

[image]

From here you can access anything that is within the `SharedCode.Core`project structure as if it was in `SharedCode.ClientOne` however the AndroidManifest.xml file is generated based on the Android Application project (SharedCode.ClientOne). This means different Android apps, with different package names using the same codebase!

Personally, I only have a single activity within the Android Application Project that acts as the entry point into the library project (such as a splash screen).

Good luck!